# Всё время появляется ошибка, что за приложение не понятно

Tags: java, android

Что это за приложение?

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Configuration android.content.res.Resources.getConfiguration()' on a null object reference
 at android.app.ActivityThread.updateLocaleListFromAppContext(Unknown Source:4)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(Unknown Source:775)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(Unknown Source:0)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Unknown Source:703)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:21)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:207)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Unknown Source:107)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Unknown Source:11)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Unknown Source:274)
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в манифесте строку:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

будет приблизительно так:

```
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

про вашу ошибку писали в [баге](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827842). Приведенный выше способ мне помог в решении данной проблемы , надеюсь и вам тоже поможет.

Comment: а манифест это где?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro?hl=ru

Comment: это я уже погуглила. мне не понятно о каком приложении идёт речь

Comment: что значит о каком приложении идет речь? это в вашем проекте есть такой файл, в который нужно вставить эту строку

Comment: какой проэкт? у меня на телефоне просто появляется эта ошибка.

Comment: я ничего не понял из того что вы написали, вы где эту ошибку видите? на телефоне ее точно не увидишь, значит вы подключили его (телефон) к пк?

Comment: именно на телефоне. вылезает окошко с ошибкой. я скопировала текст ошибки и разместила тут чтобы разобраться.к пк телефон я пока даже не подключала.короче раз уж пошли такие разговоры,я так понимаю что эта ошибка доселе неведомая ни для кого)))

Comment: приложение которое вы запускаете ваше или вы его где-то скачали?

Comment: эта ошибка появляется рандомно. я шила патч с правленным вендором. так как со старым вендором на кастомном ядре переставала работать камера. я уловила вашу мысль. мне нужно в манифест этого патча( с вендором) внести ту строку. не могу пока понять как это сделать. в телефоне не выходит

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.0 (Android SignApk)

Name: META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script
SHA1-Digest: Eo4OXWlZxc6XzdJUeak9iOY45qk=

Name: firmware-update/BTFM.bin
SHA1-Digest: PbhkCm39RrQ2zK9rIuw9MnQg5vk=

Name: firmware-update/km4.mbn
SHA1-Digest: QKk3rwOQpQz9WSOM6v8jZZOlVl8=

Name: system.patch.dat
SHA1-Digest: 2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=

Name: firmware-update/storsec.mbn
SHA1-Digest: o4V/MMVSR/2M++6xUbuf9PaaMHg=

Comment: так выглядит кусок этого манифеста. не представляю как правильно добавить туда строку

Comment: то что вы добавили имеет немного другую предметную область, измените метки вопроса и добавьте всю необходимую информацию

Comment: спасибо вам большое. я пожалуй дальше не полезу,ведь не понимаю  ничегошеньки)